# Show preloader before activity loaded

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have a heavy user interface that can delay the application load. I want to show an preloader before the UI of activity loaded. note that my ui is in xml file

Comment: i use viewpager and some fragments in my app.

Comment: You have ViewPager and many "heavy" fragment in an Activity B, and you want to show ProgressBar when showing B from Activity A?

Comment: yes . ten fragments

Comment: no i want all thing fired in one activity

Comment: Have you tried making a progress dialog?

Comment: You can place a ProgressBar in XML layout of Activity and showing it by default. When the Activity finished loading and become visible to user, the `onResume()` method will be called, place the code `progressBar.setVisibility(GONE)` inside it to hide the ProgressBar.

Comment: no problem, I hear your answer too.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
If you want to load 10 tabs in a view pager, use a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` which only loads neighboring tabs(default behavior).

If the heavy UI you specify is only the UI elements, then the app must freeze while loading it. So you'd better show a non-cancelable dialog(without animation) with loading message and after a few moment (like 200ms) load up your UI and explicitly dismiss the dialog.

But if the heavy stuffs is not just UI, maybe some calculations or image processing, just do it in a background thread while showing a dialog with progress and cancel the dialog when the task is done.

Answer (score 0):

@Hassan according to me if on clicking the launcher icon if it takes sometime for your application to render the first screen(perhaps giving a black screen in between). This needs to be corrected in your application.

On the contrary if your applications main screen requires population/retrieval of certain resources for effectively engaging the users, You can possibly do something like a splash screen(outdated) where you do all "population/retrieval" and then simply pass data to your heavy UI.
Now regarding the progress bar if this fetching of data is small, you can give an indeterminate "custom"(some moving animation that would suite your app) progress bar,else if its something like a download you can easily track its progress and show in a horizontal progressbar

Comment: my ui is xml file

Answer (score 0):

You sure can! You are describing a preloader. Here is a nice example of one https://github.com/rtheunissen/md-preloader
You'll have to add more info to your question to get a specific answer, but there are a few basic principles.

You make your life a lot easier if you use a preloader which doesn't show progress of the load, it just goes round and round, because the speed of some load processes can't be measured.

If its a data-load which is taking the time (such as a call to an API), you might want to set a variable for "loading" to true at the top of your script, then when the data has resolved, set it to "false". In your view, have a state or a conditional element which hides / unhides the preloader.

If lots of images are slowing down the page, you might want to look into "lazy-loading" or using "infinite scroll" to only show content when the UI needs to display it on screen.

Thats all the info I can give without more information on the code you have so far. Hope that helps!

Comment: i don't want to load something programically from web or inflate something.

Comment: my ui is xml file